# How can I pass an audio file as input instead of recorded voice to Google search voice?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

The following code can recognise voice using Google voice search when I speak to microphone.

How can I pass an audio file as input instead of microphone to Google search voice?

```
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speech recognition demo");
    startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
}



@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        // Fill the list view with the strings the recognizer thought it could have heard
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        mList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                matches));
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot pass an audio file through the Android speech recognition API (as of Android v4.3).

Comment: Thanks, is there othe API which I can pass an audio file as input?

Comment: @Paul I don't know if other SDKs (e.g. Nuance's) support this, open a new question for that. The answer to this question is that Android's `RecognizerIntent` does not support this as of Android v4.3.